# How do I get Vue Router beforeLeave to fire?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vue-router

I have a Vue component where I need the body element to have overflow:none but the rest of the pages should have overflow:auto. Because the body is located outside of the component, scoped css inside the component does not get applied to the body. My solution was to set the css in the route when they enter the page and undo it when they leave the page.

```
{
  path: '/report',
  name: 'Report',
  component: Report,
  meta: { requiresAuth: true },
  beforeLeave: (to, from, next) => {
    console.log('before leave')
    $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
    // next()
  },
  beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
    $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
    next()
  } 
},
```

The beforeEnter function fires and the css is applied to the body. However, the beforeLeave function is NOT firing and when I go back the rest of the site still has the body with overflow:hidden. I am only able to hit the back button to leave the page, does this not trigger the beforeLeave function? I also tried changing it to beforeRouteEnter and beforeRouteLeave like it says in the vue router documentation but that doesn't work and the beforeLeave stops working too. I also tried updating vue-router and vue to the latest versions.

Comment: there is no global guard called `beforeLeave`, but there is an `in-component` guard called `beforeRouteLeave`.

Comment: Beautiful! Didn't think of that. I can accept your answer if you'd like to write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `beforeRouteLeave` guard that is `in-component` only:

```
beforeRouteLeave(to, from, next) {
  $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');

  next()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree @Ohgodwhy solution works, but IMHO for a good reason this was tricky: because you should not do it like this. It is not a good practice to pollute your project with unscoped css, to start adding styling rules from js files or to renounce on VUE's reactivity system!

Instead, in your top level component (probably called it 'app' like we all do) add the following class:

```
<div
    id="app"
    :class="isReportPage ? 'super-duper-class-name' : 'another-super-duper-class-name'">
    ....
</div>
```

Where `isReportPage` is a computed property inside your top level components script that is checking the current route name:

```
computed: {
    isReportPage() {
      return this.$route.name === 'Report';
    },
  },
```

and the styling rules rules are inside your component's (*scoped* ;) ) css:

```
.super-duper-class-name {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.another-super-duper-class-name {
    overflow: auto ;
}
```

Now here is the magic of VUE: every time you will change the route, since `isReportPage` is a computed property it will recalculate and evaluate if the current route's name is equal to `Report`. If `true`, then it will add the `super-duper-class-name` class attribute, otherwise `another-super-duper-class-name`. So achieving the desired behaviour, have a better separation of concerns and using VUE's reactivity system.

Comment: Thanks so much for this! I went over and over this and could not think of a way to do it other than setting it with javascript. I had a feeling there was a better way!